# Display row in database with same data in particular div

Tags: php

Lets say I have data in my database with some rows having the same data.

```
id|value|message
 1|001.  |one
 2|001.  |five
 3|002.  |four
 4|001.  |hello
 5|001.  |sup
 6|002.  |sure?
```

Is it possible i `echo` all message data with `001` together in one `<div class="display"></div>` and those with `002` with the same `<div class="display></div>` There by having two `<div class="display"></div>` display the `count` of the two different values.

I have tried with `PHP` using

```
$sql =<<<EOF
SELECT value, COUNT(value) AS NumOccurrences FROM table WHERE id != '$log_id' GROUP BY value, message ORDER BY id DESC; 
EOF;
$ret = $db->query($sql);

while ($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
    $value = $row['value'];

    echo "<div class='display'>$value</div>";
}
```

But the above code `echo` six `<div class="display"></div>`. That is each `div` for each `value`

```
<div class="display">001</div>
<div class="display">001</div>
<div class="display">002</div>
<div class="display">001</div>
<div class="display">001</div>
<div class="display">002</div>
```

But i want something like this

```
<div class="display">001001001001</div>
<div class="display">002002</div>
```

Please I am new to `PHP` and searched hard for an answer. Is this possible?

Comment: try group_concat function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing query you can do something like that:

```
  $by_val = array();
  while ($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
  {
      $value = $row['value'];
      if(!isSet($by_val[$value])) $by_val[$value] = '';
      $by_val[$value] .= $value;
  }

  foreach($by_val as $key => $str) {
    echo "<div class='display'>".$str."</div>";
  }
```

Comment: Sorry please I tried using the same system with another table to echo the message but didn't work. I have made an edit to my question. Please help out. This time I am trying to echo the messages with the same value in one div.

Comment: @OkeTega change  `$by_val[$value] .= $value;` to `$by_val[$value] .= $row['message'];`